# Objects are not valid as a React child on a date props

Tags: reactjs

I'm new in react and have a lot difficulties to find a solution. I want to show my props on my class Modal component from my class Avaibalities but got the error above.

The props with date is showed in my console log when i validate but imposisble to pass that props into my div.

Avaibalities.js

```
validation = () => {

    if (this.state.showDate) {
      this.setState({
        showDate: true,
        showModal: true
      });
    } else {
      alert('Please enter a valid date')
    }
  };

render

{this.state.showDate
                &&
                <p>
                  From : {this.state.date[0].toLocaleDateString()} to :{' '}
                  {this.state.date[1].toLocaleDateString()}
                </p>
              }

<button className={'button'} onClick={this.validation}>Validate</button>

{this.state.showModal && <Modal dateModal={this.state.date} toggle={this.togglePop} />}
```

At this point my date is showed on my avaibalities component and once validated, i also got it on my Modal as props but then, i get the error with this instruction.

Modal.js

```
<div>
your dates :{this.props.dateModal}
</div>
```

I hope i was enough explicit.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood from your code that `this.state.date` is an array. so you can't call to array in react tag, so the line `your dates :{this.props.dateModal}` can't be in `<div>` tag.

You can try use `map` to show the items in the date array in the `div` tag